# Do source maps include the source text?

Tags: javascript, specifications, source-maps, browserify

When I generate a source map from minified js back to source files, does the map include the text of the source files, or do I need to host them separately?

The [HTML5 Rocks description](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) mentions the `sources` key that lists the names of source files, and explains how `mappings` maps minified line and column numbers to original line and column numbers, but suggests "You'll also need to upload your original files so the dev tools can reference and display them when necessary".

Browserify's [`debug`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#bbundleopts-cb) option generates inline source maps that show original files in dev tools without hosting the source files separately.

Does the current [source map spec](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit?pli=1) support both?

Answer (score 15):

Source maps can optionally include the original source.

From [the spec](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit?pli=1), `sourcesContent` is "An optional list of source content, useful when the “source” can’t be hosted.

source-map (the node module powering browserify source maps) supports [`sourcesContent`](https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/issues/37).  Coffeeify [populates `sourcesContent`](https://github.com/substack/coffeeify/blob/master/test/transform.js#L29) by default, inlining source text.

Comment: From comments in the spec, sounds like `sourcesContent` was added in February 2013 to match support that already existed in Chrome for self contained source maps.